# Failed animation using Lottie React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, lottie-react-native

I made an Order screen where after placing the order, I should see some **sparkle** and **thumbs** animation. But, there is no such animation. Only the text *"Your Order has been recieved"* could be seen.

Lottie Version: "lottie-react-native": "^6.3.1"

React Native Code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const OrderScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.replace("Main");
    }, 1300);
  }, []);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1 }}>
      <LottieView
        source={require("../assets/thumbs.json")}
        //ref={animation}
        style={{
          height: 260,
          width: 300,
          alignSelf: "center",
          marginTop: 40,
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
        autoPlay
        loop={false}
        speed={0.7}
      />
      <Text
        style={{
          marginTop: 20,
          fontSize: 19,
          fontWeight: "600",
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
      >
        Your Order has been recieved
      </Text>
      <LottieView
        source={require("../assets/sparkle.json")}
        style={{
          height: 300,
          position: "absolute",
          top: 100,
          width: 300,
          alignSelf: "center",
        }}
        autoPlay
        loop={false}
        speed={0.7}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default OrderScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

All the dependencies are installed as well as the directory is properly maintained inside **assets**. The lottie json files are installed from [Link](https://lottiefiles.com/) .